# Grouping Methods in Test Structure of Nunit Gui

Tags: .net, vb.net, unit-testing, nunit

Currently I have nunit's gui Test Structure setup to use Automatic Namespace suites.

I was wondering if it was possible to group up method names inside the TestFixture.

At the moment, the tree looks like

```
MyClassTest
 +Method-1 test1
 +Method-1 test2
 +Method-1 test3
 +Method-2 test1...
```

I was wondering if it's possible to have the tree look like

```
MyClassTest
 +Method1
   ++Method-1 Test1
   ++Method-1 Test2
   ++Method-1 Test3
 +Method2
   ++Method-2 Test1
```

Why do I want to do this?  It's because  I would like to just select the "Method-1" node and have it run all the tests for that method.  I just saves me the issue of checking all the tests of that method.

Background: using vb.net with vs2010 pro.

**Edit**: If I create a class inside "Myclass" called "Method1" I get the following

```
MyClassTest
 +Method-2 test1
MyCalssTest+Method-1
   +Test1
   +Test2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this by creating a `Method1` test fixture class and having the Method1Test1, Method1Test2, etc. test functions as members of that class. E.g. (in C#)

```
[TestFixture]
public class Method1
{
    [Test]
    public void Method1Test1()
    {
       ... 
    }

    [Test]
    public void Method1Test2()
    {
       ... 
    }
}
```

Comment: I created a new class called Method1 inside "Myclass" but instead of being a sub node of the "Myclass" node in the tree; it becomes a sister branch named MyBranch+Method1.

Comment: Make Myclass a namespace, and put all the Method1, Method2, etc. classes inside it - you'll get what you want.

Comment: On another note, I can get rid the awful regions that I was using to group the methods!

Answer (score 1):

NUnit's [Category](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.5.9) attribute may help too.

Comment: Good tip, I'll consider it for other uses in the future.